# Array Lists and Using Iterator

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to remove an element from an Array list in Java, I get an error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr cannot be cast to newpackage.Book";
```

What is the reason for this error and how can I fix it?

```
    public void removeBook(){
 int i=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Pleanse input isbn to be removed"));
        Iterator b=books.iterator();
        while(b.hasNext()){
            if(i==((Book)b).ISBN)b.remove();
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` is an `Iterator`, not a `Book`. You should call `b.next()` to obtain the current `Book`. And you should use a parameterized type - `Iterator<Book>` - to avoid the need to cast the current element to `Book`.

```
public void removeBook() {
    int i=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Pleanse input isbn to be removed"));
    Iterator<Book> b=books.iterator();
    while(b.hasNext()) {
        if(i == b.next().ISBN)
            b.remove();
    }
}
```

Another suggestion, instead of accessing the `ISBN` property directly, use a getter - `getISBN()`.

Answer (score 1):

Type cast b.next() to Book type object as shown below and then do the comparison. Actually this is happening because you are trying to typecast iterator type to book type

```
public void removeBook(){
int i=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Pleanse input isbn to be removed"));
        Iterator b=books.iterator();
        while(b.hasNext()){
            Book b1=(Book) b.next();
            if(i==(b1.ISBN)){
              b.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside while loop is not very clear, try simply cast Iterator object to your object and remove it

```
   Iterator itr = books.iterator();
    int i=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input isbn to be removed"));

    Book Element = "";

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
      Element = (Book) itr.next();
      if (Element.id == i) {   
        itr.remove();
        break;
      }
    }
```

PS : you can't compare a Book object with an Integer 'i', if 'i' is the id of the book to delete, you have to compare Book.id == i or with the String book name : Element.name.equals("nameInput")